# What is the fastest way to TRIM 1 million rows in Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, performance

You may know that Excel has a physical limit of 1 million rows (well, its 1,048,576 rows). I'm trying to TRIM my data containing 1 million rows in the fastest possible way.

Right now I'm using:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim cell As Range
On Error GoTo errHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
errHandler:
    If err.Number = 1004 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
cell = WorksheetFunction.Trim(cell)
cell.NumberFormat = "@"
Next cell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.Trim` will accept full joined ranges so loop the areas and not the cells.  It should cut down on the number of loops substantially.  ie `EachArea = Application.Trim(EachArea)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looing each cell could be avoided. For example,

```
Sub test()
With Range("A1:A3")
.Value = Evaluate("Trim(" & Range("A1:A3").Address & ")")
End With
End Sub
```

And if the constant range is nonadjacent then try..

**EDIT** as per comments below

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rng As Range, ar As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1") _
        .Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

For Each ar In rng.Areas
ar.Value = Application.Trim(ar)
Next ar

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `ar.Value = Application.Trim(ar)` as suggested by @ScottCraner will work,

Comment: Hi Naresh, this is really fast but also removes my header row and tabel background. I'm importing a tabel using power query editor. Is there a way to do the same but without changing the format of the tabel?

Comment: then if the header row is row 1 ... `Range("A2:Z" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` ("z" depending upon the last column) .. This will avoid the header row.

Comment: Can we set rng based on the range width of the tabel? (that would be better for me, because the data range can vary).

Comment: if you are using the listobject returned from powerquery then, `Activesheet.listobjects("Table1").range` can be used.... it need to be offset by 1 row to avoid the header row.. Look for the name of the table and edit ccordingly.. editing the answer

Comment: As far as I can see my tabel is called column in power query editor. So I changed it to Column1, but I recieve an error that the script is out of range.

Comment: Nvm I got it Naresh (wrong table name entered) ty so much!

Comment: Click anywhere on that sheet where the the power query table is generated.. and click down arrow in the name box on the left of the formula bar .. you could see the table name there.

Answer (score 4):

Solution given by Naresh works well. But you need to change your range to capture complete 1 million+ cells

It took around 5 seconds for me to trim 1 million+ cells

```
Sub TestTrim()

StartTime = Timer

With Range("A1:A" & Rows.Count)
.Value = Evaluate("Trim(" & Range("A1:A" & Rows.Count).Address & ")")
End With

TotalTime = Timer - StartTime
MsgBox TotalTime & " seconds"

End Sub
```

[image: Screenshot of time taken]

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I tested many methods but they all end up trimming individual cells and this takes forever. The spreadsheet I'm testing (not the biggest one I'll need to run the script) has 2,532,516 cells (59 * 42924) and it took only 4.5 seconds to gro from A1 to BG42924!